# Cannot create more than one clustered index on table

Tags: c#, asp.net, migration, azure-mobile-services, entity-framework-migrations

I am having the following error after typing update-database:

> Cannot create more than one clustered index on table 'dbo.AppUsers'. Drop the existing clustered index 'PK_dbo.AppUsers' before creating another.

I am working on an Azure mobile service.

I have three data models:

```
public class AppUser : EntityData
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RatingItem> userRatings { get; set; }
}

public class PlaceItem : EntityData
{
    public string PlaceName { get; set; }
    public int Group { get; set; }
    public string XCoordinate { get; set; }
    public string YCoordinate { get; set; }
}

public class RatingItem : EntityData
{
    public int Ratings { get; set; }
    public string PlaceId { get; set; }
    public AppUser user { get; set; }
}
```

It has to do with migration because :

- The initial create is in the **_MigrationHistory** table, but isn't in the migration folder in the solution explorer.
- When I add-migration AddAll, I don't get any errors, and AddAll appears in the migration folder, but not in the table.

In the context file:

```
public class ICbackendContext : DbContext
{
        public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PlaceItem> PlaceItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RatingItem> RatingItems { get; set; }
```

}

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Generally, this error message is caused by not running the Mobile Apps/Mobile Services DB generator. Entity Framework does not have an annotation for creating a clustered index that is not a primary key, so the mobile server SDK manually creates the right SQL statements to set `CreatedAt` as a non-primary key clustered index.

To resolve this, run the database generator before migrations are applied. In the `Migrations\Configuration.cs` file, include the following:

```
public Configuration()
{
   AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
   SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new EntityTableSqlGenerator());
}
```

To learn more, see [How to make data model changes to a .NET backend mobile service](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/docs/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations.md). The topic applies to **both** Mobile Services and Mobile Apps, though some namespaces are different in Mobile Apps.

Comment: Should I only use it once? I think I forgot to run Database.SetInitializer the first time, I directly commented out and created a DBMigrator.

Comment: This should be in your configuration file, so it will be run every time you do a migration.

Comment: Whoa, this is black magic. (In my case, I was trying to add Azure Mobile Apps to an existing EF database)

Comment: @lindydonna-msft I have exactly the same line in Configuration file, but I'm still getting this error. Do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: @user963935 When generating code first migration, make sure to have `modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
               new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<TableColumnAttribute, string>(
                   "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));` in your `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method on the `DbContext` config class. This will generate the correct migration code. It worked for me.

Comment: Actually my final solution was to use OfflineSync in a fresh solution - all the errors went away.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @gorillapower in comments, this piece of code is also very important.

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<TableColumnAttribute, string>( "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));
```

inside your

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

in the `DbContext` config class. Do not forget to regenerate migrations.

Comment: Can't find TableColumnAttribute. Where is this located?