# Azure App Service c# backend does not create the TodoItem table

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-web-app-service

I'm evaluating Xamarin and Azure. I would like to use App Service as a backend store.

I downloaded the C# backend and the Xamarin.Forms client application

I published the backend but it doesn't create the TodoItem table in my SQL Azure database.

It's possible to create this table by selecting the Node.js backend and click the Create TodoItem table. After this, the client application works nicely.

So, is there something to do for the C# backend to create the tables at startup?

Comment: If it is useful, please mark it as an answer that will help more communities who has  the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I plan to. I just didn't have time yet to try this solution. It looks promising anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there something to do for the C# backend to create the tables at startup?

1.Add the data connection for Azure mobile service

[image]

2.Download the C# backend, and publish it to Azure. Make sure that conection string is the same as azure mobile App.

[image]

3.After that we could visit the browser 
(http://yourmobilesitename.azurewebsites.net/tables/todoitem?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0)
it will create todoitem table for us automatically.

[image]

4.Check it from the VS Server Explorer

[image]

**Note:** If we want to connect the Azure SQL, we need to add the client ip in the Azure SQL firewall to allow our client to connect.

[image]

Another way is that we could use code-first migration easily to do that. I created a demo before, more detail please refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962943/error-after-performing-migrations-net-backend). We also could get more info from this [tutorials](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/).

Comment: Perfect !  
I activated migrations, and now everything runs fine.  
TY

Comment: I didn't have to activate the Migration, the only thing i had to do is to go to `tables/todoitem?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0` which created my tables automatically, thank you so much for your post as i was stuck for hours figuring out why it is not creating tables in my SQL_DB